# Does pthread_cond_wait(&cond_t, &mutex); unlock and then lock the mutex?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I m using `pthread_cond_wait(&cond_t, &mutex);` in my program and I m wondering why this function needs as a second parameter a mutex variable.

Does the `pthread_cond_wait()` unlock the mutex at the beginning (beginning of the execution `pthread_cond_wait()`)  and then locked when it finishes (just before leaving `pthread_cond_wait()`)?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When the first thread calls [`pthread_cond_wait(&cond_t, &mutex);`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) it releases the mutex and waits until condition `cond_t` is signaled as complete **and** `mutex` is available.

So when [`pthread_cond_signal`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal) is called in the other thread, it doesn't "wake up" the thread that waits yet. `mutex` must be unlocked first, only then there is a chance that the first thread will get a lock, which means that *"upon  successful return of [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) the mutex shall have been locked and shall be owned by the calling thread."*

Answer (score 149):

There are *many* text on the subject of condition variables and their usage, so I'll not bore you with a ton of ugly details. The reason they exist at all is to allow you to notify change in a **predicate** state. The following are *critical* in understanding proper use of condition variables and their mutex association:

- `pthread_cond_wait()` simultaneously **unlocks** the mutex *and* begins waiting for the condition variable to be signalled. thus you must *always* have ownership of the mutex before invoking it.
- `pthread_cond_wait()` returns with the mutex **locked**, thus you must unlock the mutex to allow its use somewhere else when finished with it. Whether the return happened because the condition variable was signalled or not *isn't relevant*. You still need to check your predicate regardless to account for potential *spurious wakeups*.
- The purpose of the mutex is **not** to protect the condition variable; it is to protect the *predicate* on which the condition variable is being used as a signaling mechanism. This is hands-down the most often misunderstood idiom of pthread condition variables and their mutexes. The condition variable doesn't need mutual exclusion protection; the predicate data *does*. Think of the predicate as an outside-state which is being monitored by the users of the condition-variable/mutex pair.

For example, a trivial yet obviously *wrong* piece of code to wait for a boolean flag `fSet`:

```
bool fSet = false;

int WaitForTrue()
{
    while (!fSet)
    {
        sleep(n);
    }
}
```

I should be obvious the main problem is the predicate, `fSet`, is not protected at all. *Many* things can go wrong here. Ex: From the time you evaluate the while-conditon until the time you begin waiting (or spinning, or whatever) the value may have changed. If that change notification is somehow *missed*, you're needlessly waiting.

We can change this a little so at least the predicate is protected somehow. Mutual exclusion in both modifying *and* evaluating the predicate is easily provided with (what else) a mutex.

```
pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
bool fSet = false;

int WaitForTrue()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    while (!fSet)
        sleep(n);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}
```

Well, that seems simple enough.. Now we never evaluate the predicate without first getting exclusive access to it (by latching the mutex). But this is still a major problem. We latched the mutex,  *but we never release it until our loop is finished*. If everyone else plays by the rules and waits for the mutex lock before evaluation or modification of `fSet`, they're never be able to do so until we give up the mutex. The only "someone" that can do that in this case is *us*.

So what about adding still more layers to this. Will this work?

```
pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
bool fSet = false;

int WaitForTrue()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    while (!fSet)
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
        // XXXXX
        sleep(n);
        // YYYYY
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}
```

Well, yes it will "work", but still is not much better. The period between `XXXXX` and `YYYYY` we don't own the mutex (which is ok, since we're not checking or modifying `fSet` anyway). But anytime during that period some other thread can (a) obtain the mutex, (b) modify `fSet`, and (c) release the mutex, and we won't know a thing about it until we finish our `sleep()`, once-again obtain the mutex lock, and loop around for another check.

There *has* to be a better way. Somehow there should be a way that we can release the mutex *and* begin waiting for some sort of signal that tells us a change in the predicate may have happened. Equally important, when we receive that signal and return to our code, we should already own the lock that grants us access to check the predicate data. This is *exactly* what a condition-variable is designed to provide.

---

**The Condition Variable In Action**

Enter the condition-variable + mutex pair. The mutex protects access to changing *or checking* the predicate, while the condition variable sets up a system of monitoring a change, and more importantly, doing so *atomically* (as far as you're concerned, anyway) with the predicate mutual exclusion:

```
int WaitForPredicate()
{
    // lock mutex (means:lock access to the predicate)
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

    // we can safely check this, since no one else should be 
    // changing it unless they have the mutex, which they don't
    // because we just locked it.
    while (!predicate)
    {
        // predicate not met, so begin waiting for notification
        // it has been changed *and* release access to change it
        // to anyone wanting to by unlatching the mutex, doing
        // both (start waiting and unlatching) atomically
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&mtx);

        // upon arriving here, the above returns with the mutex
        // latched (we own it). The predicate *may* be true, and
        // we'll be looping around to see if it is, but we can
        // safely do so because we own the mutex coming out of
        // the cv-wait call. 
    }

    // we still own the mutex here. further, we have assessed the 
    //  predicate is true (thus how we broke the loop).

    // take whatever action needed. 

    // You *must* release the mutex before we leave. Remember, we
    //  still own it even after the code above.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}
```

For some other thread to signal the loop above, there are several ways to do it, the two most popular below:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
TODO: change predicate state here as needed.
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
```

Another way...

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
TODO: change predicate state here as needed.
pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
```

Each has different intrinsic behavior and I invite you to do some homework on those differences and determine which is more appropriate for specific circumstances. The former provides better program flow at the expense of introducing *potentially* unwarranted wake-ups. The latter reduces those wake-ups but at the price of less context synergy. *Either* will work in our sample, and you can experiment with how each affects your waiting loops. Regardless, one thing paramount, and *both* methods fulfill this mandate:

**Never change, *nor check*, the predicate condition unless the mutex is locked**. ***Ever***.

---

**Simple Monitor Thread**

This type of operation is common in a *monitor* thread that acts on a specific predicate condition, which (sans' error checking) typically looks something like this:

```
void* monitor_proc(void *pv)
{
    // acquire mutex ownership
    //  (which means we own change-control to the predicate)
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

    // heading into monitor loop, we own the predicate mutex
    while (true)
    {
        // safe to check; we own the mutex
        while (!predicate)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mtx);

        // TODO: the cv has been signalled. our predicate data should include
        //  data to signal a break-state to exit this loop and finish the proc,
        //  as well as data that we may check for other processing.
    }

    // we still own the mutex. remember to release it on exit
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    return pv;
}
```

---

**A More Complex Monitor Thread**

Modifying this basic form to account for a *notification* system that doesn't require you to keep the mutex latched once you've picked up the notification becomes a little more involved, but not by very much. Below is a monitor proc that does not keep the mutex latched during regular processing once we've established we've been served (so to speak).

```
void* monitor_proc(void *pv)
{
    // acquire mutex ownership
    //  (which means we own change-control to the predicate)
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);

    // heading into monitor loop, we own the predicate mutex
    while (true)
    {
        // check predicate
        while (!predicate)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mtx);

        // some state that is part of the predicate to 
        // inform us we're finished
        if (break-state)
            break;

        // TODO: perform latch-required work here.

        // unlatch the mutex to do our predicate-independant work.
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

        // TODO: perform no-latch-required work here.

        // re-latch mutex prior to heading into wait
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);            
    }

    // we still own the mutex. remember to release it on exit
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    return pv;
}
```

Where would someone use something like *that* ? Well, suppose your "predicate" is the "state" of a work queue as well as some flag to tell you to stop looping and exit. Upon receiving the notification that something is "different", you check to see if you should continue executing your loop, and deciding you should continue, pop some data off the queue. Modifying the queue requires the mutex be latched (remember, its "state" is part of our predicate). Once we have popped our data, we have it locally and can process it *independent* of the queue state, so we release the mutex, do our thing, then require the mutex for the next go-around. There are many ways to code the above concept, including judicious use of `pthread_cond_broadcast`, etc. But the basic form is hopefully understandable.

This turned out to be considerably longer than I had hoped, but this is a *major* hurdle for people learning pthread-programming, and I feel it is worth the extra time/effort. I hope you got something out of it.

Comment: In your `WaitForPredicate` example, the second check for `if (predicate)` is redundant. It is known to be true at this point (otherwise, you'd still be looping.), and shouldn't change under you (assuming the signalling code is setting the condition and signalling under the mutex, which it should be doing.)

Comment: @Hasturkun Good catch. I was already thinking of the next two samples when I wrote that one. Thanks for picking that up for me. I'm so used to doing this in loops where you always check the predicate *after* the wait is signaled anyway, I completely spaced on the single-run case. Duh.

Comment: Thank you for a very good explanation; I think I finally understood the pthread_cond_t type.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I have ever seen. Thank you so much!

Comment: About pthread_cond_signal is put before or after the pthread_mutex_unlock,I am confused about your explanations,I suppose that putting signal before unlock may cause "unwarranted wake-ups",and opposite operations may cause an indirect priority inversion,Isn't it??

Comment: @HarlanChen Consider the case of signaling *after* the unlock. Suppose the mutex is unlocked but the signal hasn't been called yet. Now suppose another thread was running, acquired the mutex (which it can do because no one else is holding it), checked the predicate and found it set, so marched on rather than falling into a wait. Then, *finally* the original thread invokes the signal. The invoke would be redundant, may wake *another* thread, but now the predicate is no longer true (case: a single item pushed on a work queue). Think about how signaling before the unlock changes that.

Comment: @WhozCraig sir, I don't understand meaning of "predicate" in this subject since I'm not a native english speaker. What does it mean here? Is there any synonym of it?

Comment: @snr Think of the predicate as a containment of data that, if checked to have a specific state, indicate some course of action change in your program. Example: a counter that, if reaching the value 10, warrants some action. That counter could be changed any time by any thread. Therefore *no* thread should change it, *nor even check it*, unless the mutex that protects it from both of those operations is latched by the thread doing the change or check. That fundamental idiom is *critical* for using condition-variable/mutex duos.

Answer (score 6):

yes it unlocks, waits for the condition to be fulfilled and then waits till it can reaquire the passed mutex.

Comment: so it unlocks the mutex at the beggining and then it locks when it finish. isn't ?

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL More importantly, it is *atomic* in both the unlock and the begin-wait-state. This is the fundamental reason for condition variables and the associated mutex in the first place.

Comment: To clarify on what "atomic" means, it means by the time any other thread can observe the mutex as being unlocked (i.e. lock the mutex), the thread calling `pthread_cond_wait` is *already* blocked on the condition variable. Thus, no changes to the state protected by the mutex can be made until the calling thread is already blocked, and any future signaling done after making such changes will necessarily include the blocked thread as a candidate for waking up.

Comment: @R very well put.I hope Mohamed reads that carefully because it is *core* to using condvars and mutex pairs.

Comment: Coming to this from using POSIX interval timer's timer_create(), and setting sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD; Surprised the signal thread preempts the main thread, allows for exception processing on the instant, but when returning processing picks up just where it left off auto-magically. I don't remember old-school critical sections being that clean. Also, v.s. using signals, threads seem much easier and more useful.