# avoiding deadlock when pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have a question regarding use of pthread condition variables. As a general use case is like this

```
//thread 1:
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
do_something()
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

//thread 2:
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
```

Now I know that pthead_cond_wait will unlock mutex and go to sleep and when awaken it will lock the mutex and then return from call but how to ensure that signal from thread 2 reaches thread 1 after thread 1 is in condition wait. It could occur that thread2 runs first and then thread1 causing lost wake up.

If I use mutex lock in thread 2 again then also it may happen that thread2 will get lock it will signal and thread1 is still trying to acquire lock. This will again result in lost wake up.

How to ensure that signal from condition variable reaches thread waiting on that ?

Thanks

Comment: You ensure it by not using condition variables as predicates. They're used to signal a *change* in some predicate; not be *the predicate* themselves. Though vaguely related, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924469/does-pthread-cond-waitcond-t-mutex-unlock-and-then-lock-the-mutex/14925150#14925150), as it has some trivial, but important, aspects of how to use cvars, mutexes, and predicate changes.

Answer (score 5):

You "general use case" is not correct.  A condition variable must be paired with a condition over some shared state, known as a *predicate*.  The *general* use case is:

Thread 1:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while (!condition)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
do_something(); /* Requiring 'condition' to be true */
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Thread 2:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
do_something_else(); /* That sets 'condition' true */
pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

...where `condition` is over some shared state protected by `mutex` - for example, `condition` might be checking that a shared queue is non-empty.

There can be no lost wakeup in this structure, because the waiting thread *always* checks the condition before waiting.  If the condition is already true, it doesn't wait - and because it holds the mutex protecting the condition, it can't become true between the check and the wait either.

(Note that `pthread_cond_broadcast()` is the generally correct function to use, and `pthread_cond_signal()` is an optimisation that is applicable in many cases).

Answer (score 0):

It is completely based on your design.
You can use a bool variable(say isSignalled) to synchronize both. Something like  below(please take it as an idea)

```
//thread 1:
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
if(isSignalled == 0){
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
}
isSignalled = 0;
do_something()
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

//thread 2:
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
isSignalled = 1;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Comment: You need to use `while (isSignalled == 0)` not `if()`, because `pthread_cond_wait()` is allowed to wake up spuriously.